# Regular Expressions on powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to use regular expressions on PowerShell, but I'm with difficult to solve this question.

I have the variable

```
$appstatus = az webapp list --query "[].{state: state}"
$result = $appstatus -Match "Running"
```

The result of $appstatus is in JSON format

```
[
  {
    "state": "Running"
  }
]
```

How can store the result to be "True" or "False"

Comment: I dont think you need regex here

Comment: Can you give me some tips?
I don't have many experiences with code.

Comment: The thing is - I am not experienced in powershell.) I dont know the constructs that you can use there. Basically there should  exists some JSON psrasers for that

Comment: So "Running" == "True" , what states should map to "False"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my question, I use the commands below.

```
$azwebapp = az webapp list --query "[].{state: state}"
$appstatus = $azwebapp | ConvertFrom-Json
$result = $appstatus.state
```

Answer (score 3):

You should convert it to json instead of using regular expressions. Never implement you own json parsing. Here is a way to do it:

```bsh
$input = @'
[
  {
    "state" : "Running"
  }
]
'@
# Convert it to Json
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $input
# Check that the state member equals "Running"
$result = $json.state -eq "Running"
# Return the result
$result
```

You should do some check that the `state` member exists in `$json`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use regex, you could try this:

```
(?<="state":) ?"(\w*?)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/W25veP/3

It will capture the value of state in the first capturing group.

But I think there should be some constructs that allow you parse JSON in the language of your choice. That would in the most of the cases the best choice.

Basically you will capture "Running". I assume you want to map it to "True".

Comment: The [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) for Json parsing is `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: Yes, I found my answer with the cmdlet ConvertFrom-Json.
Cheers man!